# Django viewflow - Permission Denied

Tags: django, django-viewflow

I understand that each flow node have six (6) REST API methods. But i don't understand about /activate_next/ and /undo/. When i try both of the methods i got an error Permission Denied.

This is my example flow node:

```
create_file = flow.Start(
views.CreateProcessView
).Permission(
auto_create=True
).Next(this.check_new_file)

check_new_file = (
flow.View(
views.UpdateProcessView, fields=["file_name", "levelling_class",  "route"],
task_description="Check File")
.Permission(auto_create=True)
.Next(this.verify_new_file)
)
```

Thank you

Comment: Please share your code here

Answer (score 0):

If you using `viewflow.flow` it's not REST it's usual django view available for the admin, if the action is available.

Ex: undo available if no sibling task executed, or all siblings canceled.

Comment: i'm using `viewflow.rest`

Comment: that's part of pro version. If you have any question regarding pro, please contact over zendesk http://viewflow.io/contacts/